# Circular dependency of client libraries

Tags: microservices, circular-dependency

I am working on 2 micro-services currently, microservice A includes microservice B's SDK to call B's API and access some entity classes.
Similarly microservice B also includes microservice A's SDK and accesses microservice A's enitity classes.

Now I am facing one issue when I need to bump up the version of microservice B in microservice A and vice versa.

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already broken the cardinal rule of microservices by [tightly coupling](https://medium.com/it-dead-inside/isolating-your-microservices-through-loose-coupling-48b710e28de6) the two services.

The right answer here is going to be to refactor these services such that they properly and completely encapsulate functionality.  That could involve combining them (if B is always and completely dependent on A, they may not really be separate services), splitting them out into more services, or just shifting responsibility.

But, the path you're on with tight-coupled microservices leads to a [distributed monolith](https://www.gremlin.com/blog/is-your-microservice-a-distributed-monolith) which is unlikely to provide the benefits you're after (specifically including the co-dependent revision concern you mention here).

Here's a [good answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/333851/261154) to a related question that might offer some more insight.